# Ajax call not fetching data from model in cakephp

Tags: ajax, cakephp

My ajax is getting called but it is not fetching data from the model, so validations are not happening.In controller data is not getting picked from model and consequently the success function is not capturing any data.
I am doing in the first name field in signup tab popup.

Here is the ajax call code

JS code, validation.js

```
var ajaxHandler = function() {
$.ajax({
    method: 'post' , 
    url : '/medicare/Users/validate_form'  , 
    params : {
        field:$('#first_name').attr('id'),
        value: $('#first_name').val()
    } , 
    success: function(data){
        console.log("Successful");
    } , 
    error : function(e){
        console.log(e) ; 
    }
 }) ;
```

}

Controller action, validate_form

```
 public function validate_form(){
 if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){
 $this->request->data['User'][$this->request['form']['field']] = $this->request['form']['value'];
    $this->User->set($this->data);
    if($this->User->validates()){
      $this->autoRender = FALSE;
 }
 else{
   $error = $this->validateErrors($this->User);
   $this->set('error',$this->User->validationErrors[$this->request['data']['field']][0]);
 }
```

}
}

Comment: Where from this `$this->data` coming? It should be `$this->User->set($this->request->data)`;

Comment: Link doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @Dave Please try the link http://59655b15.ngrok.com/medicare/users/home

Comment: @Fasal I made the change still no effect..:(, the data is still not coming

Comment: Please, delete the link on your question.. Its gives access to your `XAMPP`

Answer (score 0):

There is no data sending on POST request because you wrote-

```
params: {
    field:$('#first_name').attr('id'),
    value: $('#first_name').val()
} ,
```

it should be as-

```
data : {
    field:$('#first_name').attr('id'),
    value: $('#first_name').val()
} ,
```

Comment: Still it is not showing any validation. I am new to cakephp and Ajax.I have one doubt about ajax, does it picks the model validation for the id, it will pick every validation made in the model for the id?? Thanks for your help.:)

Comment: There is lot of problems on your code.. I suggest you to master on Cakephp first without thinking about javascript, Jquery and Ajax.. Then try to implement Jquery.. It will take time but I bet you will get fun...

In my opinion, implement two way validation system.. Jquery on frontend and CakePHP(php) on backend.. You are making unnecessary Ajax call where you can do this without it..